# XSLT : 'xsl:when' condition and 'string-length' return

Tags: xslt

My XSLT file works when I am writing this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="TestLogItem[contains(Message, 'TestCase')]">
    <xsl:sort select="substring(Message, 23, 3)" data-type="number"/>
    <!-- function to order the number of the TestCases -->
    <xsl:variable name="bingo" select="substring(Message, 19, 7)"/>
```

But when I try to put in a condition depending on the length of the Message, so the variable "bingo" changes, it doesn't work :

```
<xsl:for-each select="TestLogItem[contains(Message, 'TestCase')]">
    <xsl:sort select="substring(Message, 23, 3)" data-type="number"/>
    <!-- function to order the number of the TestCases -->
    <xsl:variable name="size" select="string-length(Message)"/>
    <!-- creation of a variable to select the number of the TestCase -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$size=46">
            <xsl:variable name="bingo" select="substring(Message, 19, 7)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$size=47">
            <xsl:variable name="bingo" select="substring(Message, 19, 8)"/>
        </xsl:when> 
    </xsl:choose>
```

I tested the variable "size" and I know that works. So I guess the problem is in the condition "when".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<xsl:variable ...><xsl:choose>...</xsl:choose></xsl:variable>`, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="bingo">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$size=46">
                             <xsl:value-of select="substring(Message, 19, 7)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$size=47">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(Message, 19, 8)"/>
                        </xsl:when> 
                    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Or perhaps `<xsl:variable name="bingo" select="substring(Message, 19, -39 + $size)"/>`.

Comment: Ok I see the difference, thank you very much for your quick answer, that is perfect !